# MongoDB Replicaset - How to solve "Could not find self in current config" on Secondary node

Tags: mongodb, networking, replicaset

I am running a MongoDB server running V4.4.14 installed on VMs configured as follows:

- 1 Primary
- 2 Secondary
- 1 Arbiter

Nodes are not on the same local network and public hostnames configured on DNSs are used.

After I am trying to add another (delayed) secondary but I get the following error:

*ReplicaSet Status:*

```
rs.status().members

{
        "_id" : 5,
        "name" : "xxxx-4.xxx.xx:27123",
        "health" : 0,
        "state" : 8,
        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
        "uptime" : 0,
        ...
        "pingMs" : NumberLong(31),
        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us",
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "infoMessage" : "",
        "configVersion" : -1,
        "configTerm" : -1
    }
```

*MongoDB Logs on the Primary*

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-14T23:20:34.328+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL_HB",  "id":23974,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-16984","msg":"Heartbeat failed after max retries","attr":{"target":"xxxx-4.xxx.xx:27123","maxHeartbeatRetries":2,"error":{"code":93,"codeName":"InvalidReplicaSetConfig","errmsg":"Our replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us"}}}
```

*MongoDB Logs on the Secondary*

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-14T21:21:58.661+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":3564900, "ctx":"ReplCoord-94","msg":"Could not find self in current config, retrying DNS resolution of members","attr":{"target":"xxxx-2.xxx.xx:27123","currentConfig":{"_id":"rs0","version":133097,"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"members":[{"_id":1,"host":"xxxx-1.xxx.xx:27123","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":0.6,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1},{"_id":2,"host":"xxxx-2.xxx.xx:27123","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":0.1,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1},{"_id":3,"host":"xxxx-3.xxx.xx:27123","arbiterOnly":true,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":0.0,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1},{"_id":4,"host":"xxxx-6.xxx.xx:27123","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":0.3,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1},{"_id":5,"host":"xxxx-4.xxx.xx:27123","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":0.0,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":3600,"votes":0}],"settings":{"chainingAllowed":false,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":3000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":15,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"5df4f4f01223ca52c6ab5ebe"}}}}}
```

**MongoDB Configuration**

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 133097,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "xxxx-1.xxx.xx:27123",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.6,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "xxxx-2.xxx.xx:27123",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "xxxx-3.xxx.xx:27123",
            "arbiterOnly" : true,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "host" : "xxxx-6.xxx.xx:27123",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.3,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "host" : "xxxx-4.xxx.xx:27123",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(3600),
            "votes" : 0
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : false,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 3000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 15,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
        "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5df4f4f01223ca52c6ab5ebe")
    }
}
```

I can see the error is handled on this file:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/repl/topology_coordinator.cpp

and probably means that the secondary doesn't recognise its hostname as being 'self', hence its reporting 'not part of the config', however

- I **can** traceroute from the secondary and the route comes back to self
- I **can** connect via mongo shell from the secondary to all other nodes and from all other nodes into the secondary
- I **can** ssh from outside into the secondary node
- I **CANNOT** mongo shell or ssh using the public DNS hostname from within the secondary node

This node used to be part of the configuration without issues, was cleanly removed and now this issue has appeared

Any pointers to what can be the issue?

Comment: You say, you have 4 nodes but your `rs.conf()` shows 5

Comment: I have 4 that work fine. I am trying to add a 5th that has the issue. The config is showing the configuration with the last member being the one with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This had me wandering around for about one month.

However, as I was writing the question on this forum, that last point had me thinking.

I am still not sure why I couldn't mongo shell/ssh using the public hostname however, adding the hostname to the /etc/hosts file and pointing to the local IP (by overriding the DNS response) solved the issue.

That is: The issue was exactly what was written on the tin - the replica couldn't connect to itself by using the public hostname.

The dirty solution: I added the public hostname to the /etc/hosts file pointing to the local IP. This solved the issue.

I still need to figure out why I cannot connect via the public hostname but that is a different issue at this point.